# jQuery keeps moving element out of my table

Tags: jquery, html

Please bare with my as my jQuery is still *very* limited.

I'm working on a dynamic search feature for my user management panel so that I can look up payments quickly.

To display it, I've got this code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
            <td><strong>E-mail</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Paid</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Trans ID</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Remaining</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Other</strong></td>
        </tr>
<span class="searchResults"></span>
    </table>
```

The code I'm using to add the results into the span is this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){ 
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
   var search = $('#search').serialize();
   $.post('search.php', search, function(result){ 
        $('.searchResults').html(result);
   });
});
```

When triggered, it posts to search.php just fine, but the results display in a way I'm not expecting.

It places the results *above* the table entirely. I have no idea why or how to fix it, and Googling it hasn't been very successful. Can anyone point me at what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would need to do is add the class to your table, then append the results to the table table:

```
<table class='searchResults'>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
        <td><strong>E-mail</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Paid</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Trans ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Remaining</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Other</strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and your script will be:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){ 
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

var search = $('#search').serialize();
   $.post('search.php', search, function(result){ 
        $('.searchResults').append(result);
   });
});
```

if the search should be cleared every time you search, you should then put the header row into a variable/template, then use

```
$('.searchResults').html(template + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid HTML, everything in a table must be in TR > td

```
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
            <td><strong>E-mail</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Paid</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Trans ID</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Remaining</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Other</strong></td>
        </tr>
       <tr><td> <span class="searchResults"></span> </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that searchResults needs to return multiple columns and rows.

Comment: `​$("table tr:last-child").append("<tr><td>html</td></tr>");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: And that seems to just append it all into a single cell. `$("table tr:last-child").append(result);`